# How can I create swipe to delete for each section in UIcollecionview?

Tags: ios, swift, datatable, uicollectionview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I had a custom SwiftDataTable. which having the columns and row. I want to do swipe to delete each section. I don't have idea how to do that! any help much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Looks like that pod uses a UICollectionView as the base and doesn't support swipe to delete out of the box.  Depending on how the layout is setup, you might be able to just add your own gesture recognizer to the cell and handle it accordingly.   (there are plenty of guides on how to add swipe to delete for a collection view.

Comment: yes, but is it possible to add gesture for the entire section(UIcollecionView)? if yes, ref link please

Answer (score 0):

This is a really great pod that solves your problem
[SwipeCellKit](https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit)

Sample of how you would use it:

```
import UIKit
import SwipeCellKit

class UICollectionViewController: SwipeCollectionViewCellDelegate {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SwipeCollectionViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, editActionsForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
        guard orientation == .right else { return nil }
        let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in
            self.updateModel(at: indexPath)
        }
        // customize the action appearance
        deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "Your delete icon image")
        return [deleteAction]
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, editActionsOptionsForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> SwipeOptions {
        var options = SwipeOptions()
        options.expansionStyle = .destructive
        return options
    }
    
    func updateModel(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //What you want to happen when user swipes to delete
    }
    
}
```